# what is the basis of neighbourhood of the element $1$ in a $p-adic$ field $K$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

There is a problem in  Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*,which is in Charpter $2$ section $5$ .

The problem is :

> If $K$ is a $p-adic$ number field, then the groups $K^{*n}$, for $n$ belongs to $N$, form a
>   basis of neighbourhoods of $1$ in $K^*$.

I think it is very clear that $K^{*n}$ is an open subgroup of $K^*$ for each integer $n$,but how to check they form a basis of neighbourhood of $1$ in $K^*$?
This really puzzled me these days,so please offer me some help and show how to solve it,thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, a proof that the sets $(K^{\times})^n$ are *open* can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/nth-powers-in-the-p-adics/17767#17767).

As for the fact that these sets form a n.h. basis of $1$, this is not actually
true if you give $K^{\times}$ its usual topology, but it is true if you replace
$K^{\times}$ by $\mathcal O_K^{\times}$ (where $\mathcal O_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$).

Verifying this is (in my view) easier than proving the openness.

Hint: Consider what happens when $n$ is divisible by a huge power of $p$.

Extended hint, in response to comment from OP below: If you are not familiar with these ideas, then it would be best to start with the case $K = \mathbb Q_p$.  Consider $(\mathbb Z_p^{\times})^{p-1}$.  Show that this
consists precisely of the set $1 + p \mathbb Z_p$.

Now if you take an integer $x$ that is $\equiv 1$ mod $p$, what can you say
about $x^{p^n}$?  It is certainly congruent to $1$ mod $p$, but can you do
any better?

Comment: Thank you very much! But could you please show your answer with details,I am not quite familiar with those topological concepts. Thanks!

Comment: @curiosity: Dear curiosity, I have extended my hint.  If it still doesn't make sense, then perhaps you should ask another, more basic question, say about the nature of the topology on $\mathbb Q_p$.  You won't be able to solve Neukirch's question unless you have a solid understanding of the topology on $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb Q_p^{\times}$.  Regards,

Comment: Dear,MattE.Thank you for your extended hint and advise, but I can understand what happens when we consider this question in $Q_p$,but I still can not make it that clear when the field is a $p−adic$ number field....could you please excuse my foolishness and show me how to prove $O_k ^{*n}$ form a basis of neighbourhood of $1$? Thank you!

Comment: @curiosity: Dear curiosity,  The multiplicative group of the residue field of $\mathcal O_K$ has finite order, so raising to that order, we land in subgrop of $\mathcal O_K^{\times}$ that is trivial mod the uniformizer.  Now this subgroup is pro-$p$, and so raising to higher powers of $p$, we can put ourselves inside any open n.h of $1$.  (In short, it is exactly the same as the $\mathbb Q_p$-case, just with $p-1$ replaced by the order of the multiplicative group of the residue field.)  Regards,

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but if anyone sees this comment, could they please clarify exactly what we’re supposed to prove here? As you say yourself, the statement in Neukirch is actually false, and I am unable to figure out from your post what the correct statement is.

Comment: @Vik78: I believe one correct statement is to replace $K$ with $\mathcal{O}_K$, that is show that $\mathcal{O}_K^{*n}$ is a basis of neighborhoods of $1$ in $\mathcal{O}_K^*$